# Bindings set hidden, if string value is larger than

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I have a ButtonCell, which i want to hide using bindings, when the NSString value at keyPath

```
key1.key2
```

is larger than 3 character, but the binding offers me only

```
NSIsNotNil, NSIsNil,...
```

which doesnt apply in this case

Answer (score 0):

Well In your XIB select you button then as attached in the screens shot follow the steps:-

1. [image: List item]
2. Now in your header and implementation file create property and synthesize variable of `BOOL isEnable;`
3. And on the basis of your string count set it NO and YES.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this method:

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

in this one you can enable and disable cell according the value in key path

Comment: but i want to do it automatically using bindings in OB

Comment: Buddy, this does not answers the question... It needs to be binded, not triggered though method call.